# Picasso library in Android Studio not loading image from URL also not loading from drawable resource file

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso Library to load images from URL but it is not working, I tried multiple URLs even they mentioned on their official website which is https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg

Then I tried to load a drawable image from resource directory it is also not loading all I am seeing is blank screen no error nothing. Can someone please suggest what is wrong?

- I have taken the Internet Permission.
- I have used the latest version of Picasso from Github.

Here's a code.

Activity java file:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView iv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        iv2 = findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_terrain_black_24dp).into(iv2);
    }
}
```

Activity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Picasso Implementation:
`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`

By the way, my minimum SDK version is 16 and target SDK is the current default 29 if this info could be helpful.

Comment: Nope didn't work, and nothing caught in debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a placeholder and an error image.

With Picasso you can set directly them after `Picasso.get()` with `.placeholder` and `.error`

Also you should enable Picasso debugging.

These three elements will probably give us something more to understand why your image is not loaded.

Comment: Tried error too but it's not loading it in anyway, now started using glide and nothing caught in debugging. But I will definitely try your answer also.

Comment: If you have time, please can you try to use Picasso in your system and let me know if it is working or not. If you are free if not no problem, just wanna know my device have any issue or something because I am sure the code is fine because there is nothing in code. Glide works fine for me now. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Same image is getting loaded in error but not loading in get() method.